# Is it possible to move after and before methods to interface with Java 8?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

The problem is that my test class is already implemented some class:

```
public class MainTest extends ExecutionContext ...
```

Thus, I can move general logic to parent class as it is usually done:

```
public class TestBase {
    protected final String baseUrl = Config.getProperty(Config.TEST_HOST);
    protected final String driverName = Config.getProperty(Config.BROWSER);
    protected final DriversEnum driverInstance = DriversEnum.valueOf(driverName.toUpperCase());

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void start() { 
       ...
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void end() {
        Logger.logDebug("Start AFTER Method");
    }
```

I tried to use Java 8 features like `default` or `static` methods. Here is a sample:

```
@Listeners(TestListener.class)
public interface ITestBase {
    String baseUrl = Config.getProperty(Config.TEST_HOST);
    String driverName = Config.getProperty(Config.BROWSER);
    DriversEnum driverInstance = DriversEnum.valueOf(driverName.toUpperCase());

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    default public void start() {
        ...
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    default public void end() {
        ...
    }
```

When I run typical TestNG test method, like:

```
public class AppUiDemo implements ITestBase {
    @Test
    public void checkWebDriverCreation() {
      ...
    }
```

`start()` and `end()` methods haven't called.

***Is it possible to use interface with any implementation for execution code before and after test methods with TestNG?***

Comment: Not yet released https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/CHANGES.txt#L36

Comment: @juherr Do you know which version it will available? Current, for now, is [6.11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng)

Comment: Next release (6.13, soon). 6.12 is available on jcenter but not on maven central https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1506

Answer (score 1):

Default methods in interfaces are not yet supported but they will be in the next release (https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/CHANGES.txt#L36) which should be 6.13 (release soon).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but the version of TestNG that allow using interface methods in tests is not released yet. You need to download it from [this](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots) repository.

If you use ***Maven*** you can specify additional repository in your `pom.xml`:

```
<repository>
    <id>testng</id>
    <name>testng</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
</repository>
```

And then add TestNG dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**Example:**

```
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DummyTest implements ITest {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeTest() {
        System.out.println("before from class");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("I am test1");
    }
}
```

and **ITest** interface

```
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public interface ITest {

    @BeforeMethod
    default void beforeDefaultInterface() {
        System.out.println("before from default interface method");
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    static void beforeStaticInterface() {
        System.out.println("before from static interface method");
    }
}
```

The output of the test above will be:

```
    before from default interface method
    before from static interface method
    before from class
    I am test1
```